# select ids that doesn't have a specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the schema below:

```
+---------+--------+
|studentId | course | 
+---------+--------+
|1        | 2      | 
|1        | 3      | 
|1        | 4      | 
|1        | 5      | 
|2        | 4      | 
|2        | 5      | 
+---------+--------+
```

and I want to perform a query to get student Ids that don't have course 2 and 3

```
select * from students where course not in (2,3);
```

but it returns Students IDs 1 and 2 and I want it to return Student ID 2 only.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select * from students where studentId not in -- exclude all students from course 2 & 3
(
    --find all the students in course 2 & 3
    select distinct studentId --could be duplicates might as well grab a distinct list.
    from students 
    where course in (2,3)
)
```

Comment: Strictly logical "don't have course 2 and 3" means that. However the provided code example in the question, suggests that OP actually wanted to filter out students where course 2 OR course 3 are set.

Answer (score 2):

*This answers assumes that OP wants to filter out students that have either course 2 or course 3 or both of them set.*

At first, find all students, who have course 2 or 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentId
FROM students
WHERE course IN (2,3)
```

Then, find all students, who are not in that list

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE studentId NOT IN (...)
```

If you only want to return a list of studentIds, without their courses, replace `*` with `DISTINCT studentId`.

Put those together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentId
FROM students
WHERE studentId NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT studentId
  FROM students
  WHERE course IN (2,3)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another query using `having` to filter out students that have courses 2 or 3

```
select studentId
from students
group by studentId
having sum(course in (2,3)) = 0
```

Comment: This would be correct: select studentId
from student
group by studentId
having sum(course in (2,3)) < 2;

Comment: @Strawberry I can read the question either way but yes if op only wants to exclude students that have taken both courses then changing to <2 would work

Comment: Actually, you're right. I read it the other way, but re-reading it, both interpretations are fair. Still, I suspect I'm right ;-) If you make some kind of edit, I'll give you your point back.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select
    *
from
    students s
where
    not exists ( select
                     1
                 from
                     students ss
                 where
                     ss.studentID = s.studentID
                     and ss.course in (2,3));
```

Comment: This won't work as your subquery will always return 1 for each record in the students table

Comment: @JanR Good catch, I added the condition into the where clause

Comment: you are still doing a select 1 from student, which will return the value 1 for each record.

Comment: I see what you're doing now, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NOT IN and writing a subquery that pulls for each student who is taking courses 2 or 3. That is, if you are looking for students who are not taking course 2 or 3. If you are looking to exclude students who are taking BOTH courses, this will need to change a little bit. Let me know if that is the case.

Start by writing the subquery, which is easy enough:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students
WHERE course = 2 OR course = 3
```

Then, you can select from your table again using the NOT IN operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentid
FROM students
WHERE studentid NOT IN (SELECT studentid
                        FROM students
                        WHERE course = 2 OR course = 3);
```

And [it works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ba12/10)!

Comment: @Strawberry what is it?

Comment: Sorry - I only realised later that the question is open to interpretation, so you may be correct after all. Edit your post somehow and I'll give you your point back

Comment: @Strawberry I understand now from reading some of the other answers. Yeah, this one is definitely open for interpretation until OP can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.studentid 
           FROM student x
           LEFT 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT studentid 
                  FROM student 
                 WHERE course IN(2,3) 
                 GROUP 
                    BY studentid 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ) y
             ON y.studentid = x.studentid
          WHERE y.studentid IS NULL;
```

(of course, it's highly unlikely that a table holding students and courses would be called `student`. `enrolment` might be a better title)

Answer (score -1):

JR's query will perform poorly MySQL < 5.6 and only performs an OR not an AND on course.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM foo AS missingfoo 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT id FROM foo AS foo1 
           JOIN foo AS foo2 USING (id) 
           WHERE foo1.course=2 
           AND foo2.course=3
          ) AS z 
USING (id) WHERE z.id IS NULL GROUP BY id;
```